# Getting "Input string was not in a correct format" with File picker

Tags: xamarin.forms, filepicker

I am trying to pick a file using the following code

```
                            FileData fileData = new FileData();

                            fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();

                            if (fileData != null)
```

and getting the following exception

```
  at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException (System.Boolean overflow, System.String overfl

owResourceKey) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Number.Parsing.cs:1781 
  at System.Number.ParseInt64 (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles styles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Number.Parsing.cs:246 
  at System.Int64.Parse (System.String s) [0x0000a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Int64.cs:106 
  at Plugin.FilePicker.IOUtil.GetPath (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri) [0x000ab] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\IOUtil.android.cs:64 
  at Plugin.FilePicker.FilePickerActivity.OnActivityResult (System.Int32 requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data) [0x00039] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\FilePickerActivity.android.cs:151 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

and the exception message saying "Input string was not in a correct format".

I am trying it for so long, but unable to find the solution.

Android version - 10

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: Try to use [Xamarin.Essentials: File Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android).

Comment: I am using the latest stable version for Xamarin.Essentials but FilePickerAsync() is not accessible.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Done @JackHua-MSFT, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using the latest stable version for Xamarin.Essentials but
> FilePickerAsync() is not accessible.

In the latest version for Xamarin.Essentials, to get :

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

public async void getFile()
{
    var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync();

    //...
}
```

The `ReadExternalStorage` permission is required:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Refer: [Xamarin.Essentials: File Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android)